# How to display this console.log data in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We created a function that shows users who are online. It works fine in console log but I want to display p as the result if user is online.  Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.emit('online', { room: 'global', user: this.user.username });
    this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
      this.GetUserData(this.name);
    });
  ...
  ...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.socket.on('usersOnline', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Above console.log(data)
 displays the detail of all users who are online inside the console. What should be added instead of console.log for displaying condition in front-end?
We added something like this:

```
  CheckIfOnline(name) {
    const result = _.indexOf(this.onlineusers, name);
    if (result > -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <p class="" *ngIf="CheckIfOnline(user.username)">online</p>
```

But it doesn't show because something is missing in CheckIfOnline function. this function is just a prototype. I assume it should work with ngAfterViewInit. What should I add instead of that console.log and fix checkifonline to communicate with each other and display that p tag when the user is online?

Answer (score 0):

You could define boolean flag variable and set in `ngAfterViewInit` method. hth

```
public isOnline: boolean = false;

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.socket.on('usersOnline', data => {
     /** Check user name exist in data contains */
     this.isOnline = /* [write a logic check this.user.username exist in data ] */
    });
  }

 <p class="" *ngIf="isOnline">online</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Should I remove CheckIfOnline function completely?

Comment: it shows lots of errors in this line:
this.isOnline = [check this.user.username exist in data ] under exist in is online, check. What syntax is this? The complete line is underlined with errors.

Comment: Oh, You have to  write a logic to replace the  [check this.user.username exist in data ].

Comment: I've added something like this:
this.isOnline = data.some(d=>d.name == user.name);  but it shows online p tag for all users even for those ones who are offline while in console log it works correctly.

Comment: Oh, Is that <p used for all the users or just current user? This solution will work for current user.